# Bind input type submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have Registration.html fail, which contains registration form. The other failure is in KinveyRequester.js

```js
function registerUser(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    let userData = {
      username: $("#registerUsername").val(),
      password: $("#registerPassword").val()
    };
    $.ajax({
      method: "POST",
      url: kinveyBaseUrl + '/user/' + kinveyAppKey,
      headers: kinveyAppAuthHeaders,
      data: userData,
      success: registerSuccess,
      error: handleAjaxError
    });

    function registerSuccess(userInfo) {
      saveAuthInSession(userInfo);
      showInfo("User Successfully Registered");
    }
```

The Question is:

How can i bind and when i clicked "Register" button it runs correctly and register a user. [Here](http://pastebin.com/RgFJCCWe) is the Register.html fail

Comment: You have two jQueries installed - any console messages?

Comment: So do bind "click" or "submit" events?

Comment: I don't have any console messages. That's the button

<input type="submit" value="Register" class="btn btn-info btn-block">

Answer (score 0):

You can bind registerUser function with your submit button simply by using jQuery [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#reg-btn').on('click', registerUser);
});
```

But it's better to bind on form's submit event:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#your-form').on('submit', registerUser);
});
```

but in that case you have to return false at the end of the your registerUser function in order to prevent default submit behaviour.

Comment: Not true. The e is passed: https://jsfiddle.net/2bvuc6on/ - your second example is now identical to mine

Answer (score 0):

Do not bind the submit button, instead bind the form submit
Also move the inline onload:

```
$(function() {
  startApplication();
  $("#registerUserForm").on("submit",registerUser); 
});
```

Also you need a } between these:

```
  });
} <<<<<<<<<<
function registerSuccess(userInfo) {
```

Example of the submit is here https://jsfiddle.net/2bvuc6on/ since StackSnippets block submit

Answer (score -1):

for example like: `$('input[type="submit"]').on( 'click', registerUser() );` or with a class for the submit button like `$( document ).on( 'click', '.yourSubmitClass', registerUser() );`

Comment: You need to remove the () from the function you are passing.